# Ruby - Oci8 - Call funtion with rowtype not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oracle11g, oci8

I have an oracle function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION (MY_ID IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN vendedor%rowtype AS 
    res vendedor%rowtype; 
BEGIN  
    select * into res
    from vendedor
    where id = MY_ID;    
    return res;  
END MY_FUNCTION;
```

And I want to call this function from my ruby code using `oci8 gem`. This is my ruby code:

```
connectString = ENV['DB_CONNECTION']
conn = OCI8.new(connectString)
cursor = conn.parse ('begin :ret := MY_FUNCTION(:MY_ID); end;') 
cursor.bind_param(':MY_ID', '123', String)
cursor.bind_param(':ret', nil, OCI8::RAW) # This is the question
cursor.exec()
result = cursor[':ret']
cursor.close
conn.logoff
```

What is the parameter's bind type of `:ret` variable?

To execute this code throw this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 1, 
column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `cursor.bind_param(':ret', nil, OCI8::RAW)`

with 
      `cursor.bind_param(':ret', OCI8::Cursor)` would do the trick,

but you need to convert your function to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION (MY_ID IN VARCHAR2) RETURN sys_refcursor AS 
    res sys_refcursor; 
BEGIN  
    open res for
      select *
        from vendedor
          where id = MY_ID;    
    return res;  
END MY_FUNCTION;
```

to prepare to return `sys_refcursor` type

For get the result in ruby code:

```
result = cursor[':ret']
while r = result.fetch_hash
    retFinal = r
end
```

retFinal variable has the cursor's last result